# Stack dotplot labels using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a simple dotplot that contains 100+ points, some of which are grouped close together. I need the points to be individually labeled, but I would like to stack the labels for points that are close together on top of each other.

Basically, I would like to create a similar dotplot with labeling to the graph below.

[image: dot label example]

As a code example, consider the following code where I would like to add the car name to the dotplot in a way similar to the graphic.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = .4, stackdir = "centerwhole") +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

Comment: This can certainly be done in ggplot, but would require specifying exactly where you want the labels. Getting a nice aesthetic result requires knowledge of the final image size, the font used, the length of the labels, how closely bunched the data are, etc etc. I don't think a simple algorithm could get consistent results, so there aren't any extension packages that could do this automatically. The closest is ggrepel, but that won't give you the same polished aesthetic as the sample image.